# dataTable plugin, reload table, fnDestroy() destroys the wrapper AND its content : "Node was not found"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Well, after some AJAX I use dataTable.fnDestroy() and reinitialize the table to refresh the data (for sorting, etc...)

It worked some days ago, with a simple table and now I can't do it again. I have this error:

**Node was not found** with the following line error in datable.js : "<kbd>*orig.insertBefore( table, settings.nTableReinsertBefore );*</kbd>->line 8853"

It's strange because I can initialise every tables :

```
$('table[id*="classement"]').each(function(){
    if (condition){
        $(this).dataTable({
            columnDefs: [
               {type: 'non-empty-string', targets: [1,2]} 
            ],
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            aoColumns : [
                  { "sWidth": "7%"},
                  { "sWidth": "65%"},
                  { "sWidth": "20%"},
                  { "sWidth": "8%"}
                ]
         });
    }
    else if{
         ...
         ...
         etc...
 });
```

But if I try just after to delete them, I have the previous error in the console (recent browser version):

```
$('table[id*="classement"]').each(function(){
    $(this).dataTable().fnDestroy();
});
```

So I can't reinitialize my tables because destroy is having an issue.

Same with `"bDestroy":true,`

**Edit :** In fact it works, it destroys the 'div wrapper' and its content, is there a way to keep the table after destroy which is normally the default behaviour ?

See these screen :

[image]

and after

```
$('#classement_ownranking_music').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

[image]

So it destroys the wrapper but also the table. Any idea?

Comment: Hard to reproduce the error, it works alright without generating any errors, see -> http://jsfiddle.net/ukmjvf1k/ what version of dataTables?

Comment: "_is there a way to keep the table after destroy (without dataTable initialisation)?_"? What do you mean? The original table is kept upon fnDestroy, unless you pass true, `.fnDestroy(true)`.

Comment: See my edits, I have several dataTables which are hidden/shown on click, and when I try to destroy one, it destroys also the table, not just the wrapper. It's not the default behaviour like you said but I can't find what is special in my table to do that...

Comment: It doesn't come from the table, see http://jsfiddle.net/Fanch/ofpgumqs/ . Could there be a js conflict between libraries ? ;I use `bootstrap modal dialog`, `jquery ui modal dialog confirmation`.